# Put two textviews above fragment that contains a Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have the following code that displays two textviews and below I have a fragment where I display a map of Google Maps. But still I'm not able to display them in this way:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="@string/pos_actual" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtGeoposition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/map"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Also I want to limit the height of the fragment for not to fill the rest of the parent layout, just a few pixels of height, because below the map I want to put other controls to display.

How can I achieve this controls to put them in this way?

Thank you in advance

My code updated:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="@string/pos_actual" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtGeoposition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/map"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="@string/pos_actual" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **Put two textviews above fragment**: Remove `alignParentBottom` from both TextViews. Also, in the Fragment, change **above** to **below**

Comment: That's it. I guess I can limit the height of the fragment for not to fill the rest of the layout?

Comment: Your choice. I'd set it to fill (match_parent) the rest of the space. Or you can use wrap_content. Or you could have some other View anchored to thebottom and set the map also above this one.

Comment: When you say have some other View anchored to the bottom you mean that I use a linearlayout or relativelayout?

Comment: Whatever you want in your RelativeLayout can be anchored to its sides (top, bottom, right, left). Even just another TextView. Or a whole layout.

Comment: See my code updated. I'm not able to display a layout below the fragment. The fragment fills all the screen at the bottom.

Comment: Finally I could put at the bottom of the screena layout. See my code updated for details. Thank you Funkystein

Comment: The LinearLayout is not needed. It adds a level to your View Hierarchy. But the RelativeLayout should be closed at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Code finally updated and correct:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="@string/pos_actual" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtGeoposition"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/map"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footerLayout" />

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="@string/pos_actual" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your TextViews after the fragment.

If you want to put space at the bottom, put a margin or use `layout_above="@+id/someviewId"` that reference a view that will be at the bottom (with alignParentBottom par instance).

Comment: **Put two textviews above fragment**

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem**
see its very simple you just need textview under framelayout..

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapfrag"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="96dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text View 1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text View 2"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```